# Home folder keeps re-opening

Tags: home-directory, restore, minimize

So I click on my file cabinet button at left, home folder comes up (OK).  I access whatever drive I like, then minimize the new folder (OK).  Click the file cabinet button again to restore the folder, and instead of the un-minimized, restored folder, ANOTHER instance of the home folder comes up (NOT OK).  Click file cabinet button again, both choices hover and I close the new Home folder.

Is there a way to minimize and RESTORE a folder window without hassling back through home folder in a second instance?

Comment: This is a bug, I encountered this myself for a while. Does it keep happening after a system restart?

Comment: It has always been like that for me since Trusty. In Vivid instead, they moved this bug to the menu entry for emptying the trash can in the launcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug/feature with Unity and it's fairly simple to work around.

Instead of just clicking on the Nautilus (file browser) icon, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Click or scroll the mouse wheel over the icon and it should open up the already open window!

Comment: 1. Restarting the computer did not fix my issue.      
2. SHIFT + clicking on the file box icon did not work - same issue of a brand new home folder came up.      
3, hovering over the  file box icon and scrolling the wheel WORKED!!

Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewOwen Ah. Glad I could help. If you think my answer is good enough of a solution, please consider upvoting it and marking it as answer (clicking the checkmark button.) That's the common way of thanking people on this site and it makes it easier for people who might read this question/answer later to see what the solution was!